# Why the instance methods tab in JDK 8 API Documentation?

Tags: java, api, instance, java-8

Just saw methods tabs in JDK 8 API Documentation and I don't know why there is a tab of instance methods in an interface (say in javax.swing.Action) as there can't be static keyword allowed in a method in interface because then that method will be class method, static method, right! So, every method in interface is an instance method, then why there are tabs which separate instance methods and abstract methods in an interface?

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong about interfaces.

In Java 8 you [can define `static` methods on interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html):

> In addition to default methods, you can define static methods in
>   interfaces. (A static method is a method that is associated with the
>   class in which it is defined rather than with any object. Every
>   instance of the class shares its static methods.)

[JLS §9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4)

> An interface can declare static methods, which are invoked without
>   reference to a particular object.

**EDIT**

A comment asked

> Can the static method be called on the interface or only on classes
>   implementing the interface?

The answer is of course you can:

```
//separate file
public interface MyInterface {

    static void printMe() {
        System.out.println("Thing");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyInterface.printMe();
}
```

Comment: Is that link specific to Java8?

Comment: @Java1 Yes. You were not allowed to declare `static` methods on interfaces in Java 7 (nor default methods in fact).

Comment: Can the static method be called on the interface or only on classes implementing the interface?

Comment: @Java1: In a static interface method you can call other static interface methods as well!

Comment: @Java1 The containing type, be it an interface or a class, of a static method is just a namespace for it. There is nothing wrong with allowing a static method to be qualified by an interface name.